# Ext.List messes up rows and display after going forward on a view?

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I have a navigation view that contains a list view with a list of items, and when you click the item it pushes a new list detail page. Everything works fine and dandy, but when I go back to the previous list, it shows up all discombobulated.

I've tested this in Webkit and Mobile webkit browsers and the result is the same. I'm looking for any possible feedback or suggestions that might point me towards a) fixing the problem or b) repainting the window when this happens so it corrects itself.

Example:

[image: Example Image]

Navigation view:

```
Ext.define('CA.view.speaker.Card', {
  extend: 'Ext.NavigationView',
  xtype: 'xSpeakerCard',

  config: {
    title: "Speakers",
    iconCls: "team",
    autoDestroy: false,

    items: [
      { xclass: 'CA.view.speaker.List' }
    ]
  }

});
```

List view:

```
Ext.define('CA.view.speaker.List', {

  extend: 'Ext.List',
  xtype: 'xSpeakerList',

  config: { 
    title: "Speaker List",
    store: "Speakers",
    fullscreen: true, 
    grouped: true,
    indexBar: true,
    itemTpl: [
        '{first_name} {last_name}'
    ]
  }
});
```

Detail View being pushed:

```
Ext.define('CA.view.speaker.Detail', {

  extend: 'Ext.Container',
  xtype: 'xSpeakerDetail',

  config: {
    layout: 'vbox',
    scrollable: 'vertical',
    title: '',
    items: [
      { 
      xtype: 'xSpeakerDetailInfo', 
      docked: 'top' 
    },
    { 
      xtype: 'list', 
      store: 'SpeakerSessions',
      id: 'speaker-detail-info-session-list',
      flex: 3,
      itemTpl: [
        '{title}'
      ],
      items: [ 
        { 
        xtype: 'listitemheader', 
        cls: 'dark',
        html: 'Sessions'
      }
      ]
    }
    ]
  }

});
```

Comment: could you post the full code? Especially the second view pushed...

Comment: @abellina i've added the full code above

Comment: Did you override any CSS ? Also, it's better to have your fullscreen: true, on the main view which is the navigation view, not the list within.

Comment: Heh... "discombobulated". Not sure what the issue might be, but I would tinker with the `fullscreen` and `layout` config options on the `List`. Also, can you see any classes that were added to the list when you navigate back that weren't there the first time around?